# df from busybox shows different number of inodes than that of tune2fs

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, busybox, coreutils

we have Beaglebone black based custom board,

we have busybox shell including coreutils.
busybox version is BusyBox v1.20.2 (2017-10-16 16:39:36 EDT)
now we wanted to check the inode usage in each partition,

So when I run `df -i` I get following output

```
# df -i
Filesystem              Inodes      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                     125         9       116   7% /
/dev/root                  125         9       116   7% /
tmpfs                       62         0        62   0% /tmp
tmpfs                       62         0        62   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       62         0        62   0% /var/run
tmpfs                       62         0        62   0% /var/spool/cron
tmpfs                       62         0        62   0% /var/sftp
/dev/mmcblk0p18             15         0        15   0% /var/db
/dev/mmcblk0p19             64         0        64   0% /var/firmware
```

now when I run tun2fs to get inode count I get following output

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/mmcblk0p18 | grep -i inode
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse
Inode count:              15360
Free inodes:              15346
Inodes per group:         1920
Inode blocks per group:   240
First inode:              11
Inode size:               128
Journal inode:            8
Journal backup:           inode blocks

# tune2fs -l /dev/mmcblk0p19 | grep -i inode
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse
Inode count:              65536
Free inodes:              65525
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Journal inode:            8
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

I don't understand why it is different.
Inodes informed by busybox for a partition e.g. mmcblk0p18 is `15`

And same thing reported by tune2fs is `15*1024 = 15360`
same thing for partition mmcblk0p19.

I am not understanding why it is reported that way in busybox because inode size is also different in both the partitions 128 and 256 for partition 18 and 19 respectively.

Can someone help or give any pointers?

Comment: It looks like you may have found a bug in Busybox.  Disk space is supposed to be displayed in block counts like that (and the 1k matches the default in GNU df and busybox), inodes aren't though.  You might consider reporting this to the developers and see what they say.

Comment: Thank you Austin, sure I will report it to busybox developer and will update their reply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the buglist of busybox but did not find any reference of my error.
Fact that busybox df is working as expected in my ubuntu machine, I looked at the busybox configuration.
Initially I was enabling below two configs only,

```
CONFIG_DF=y
CONFIG_FEATURE_DF_FANCY=y
```

And with that I was not able to get expected output. However once I enabled below configuration `df -i` started working as expected.

```
#
# Common options for df, du, ls
#
CONFIG_FEATURE_HUMAN_READABLE=y
```

So culprit was this common config in busysbox config.